# Error while providing configuration in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

I want to convert csv to pdf using python script hence using **pdfkit** and **wkhtmltopdf** for converting.
I need to configure **wkhtmltopdf** path.
I did the same but I am getting below error.

code used:-

```
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf')

Error:-IOError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf"
```

Note :-wkhtmltopdf is present in the above directory only but still I am getting an error as not present.
How to resolve this?